# Continue viewing progress after closing the console: IMAPSYNC

Tags: email, email-server, migration, imapsync

I have mounted a VPS with ubuntu, I have installed IMAPSYNC to perform the migration of a pair of mailboxes.

I connect from my mac, through this VPS via ssh and from there I am managing the migration.

From what I have been able to prove, IMAPSYNC continues with the migration even though the connection between my mac and the VPS (ssh) is lost, that seems great to me, because it continues to work without having to be connected (via ssh)

However, I would like to know how can I see the progress of the migration after losing the connection, is there a way to go back to the progress without having to run the command again?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see what the imapsync command is doing, you can reconnect to the host via ssh and follow the log file with the command "tail -F":

```
tail -F  LOG_imapsync/2020_07_21_00_18_34_654_tata_gilles...txt
```

Usually on Linux, when an ssh session ends then the foreground command launched from it (imapsync here) is also ended.

If you want to reconnect at previous sessions, take a look at the commands "screen" or "tmux".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I make IMAPSYNC always stop running despite logging out of the console?

Comment: Kill it before logging out. Hit ctrl-c twice or kill it with the kill command.